# Difference Ktlint vs. lint?

Tags: android, kotlin, lint, ktlint

[According to this article, ktlint is an automatic linter with a built-in code style checker.](https://sourcelevel.io/blog/ktlint-or-detekt-which-linter-to-choose)

**When I decide to use ktlint, what is the difference between lint and ktlint?**

lint is optimized for Android

ktlint is optimized for Kotlin?

**How is ktlint performing with integration systems like Bamboo?**
Will it apply autoamtically?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Linting** is the process of checking the source code for Programmatic as well as Stylistic errors. **Lint** and **Linting** is more general and doesn't apply to Android only.

**Ktlint** is more specific and checks rules more specific to Kotlin language.

I personally use **detekt** for checking my code. It has more configuration options.

> How is ktlint performing with integration systems like Bamboo? Will it
> apply autoamtically?

Linting doesn't depend on integration with other systems. It just checks any code you have.

You can add pre-commit hook, to check your code with **ktlint** before commits:

[Video Tutorial and Explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eysVDO2_X0s)

[Tutorial 1](https://proandroiddev.com/ooga-chaka-git-hooks-to-enforce-code-quality-11ce8d0d23cb)

[Tutorial 2](https://ktlint.github.io/)

Comment: Ok, I remeber in earlier projects we had github configured that way, it did not accept unformatted code. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @PavelPipovic I've updated my answer with detailed instructions for checks before pushing code to GIT. Follow Video tutorial, it is easy.